# Delphi how to implement OnAfterMonitorDpiChanged

Tags: delphi, highdpi

I am using a subclass `TMyForm = class( tForm )` for all my forms.
I do not want to add the same code in all my forms and would like to override the `OnAfterMonitorDpiChanged` and add the common code into TMyForm.

How I can do that?
Or do I have to use
`procedure WMDpiChanged(var Message: TWMDpi); message WM_DPICHANGED;` ?

Delphi 10.3.3

Comment: Read about form inheritance.

Comment: @TLama form inheritance does not help much here - OnAfterMonitorDpiChanged is property and there is no virtual DoAfterMonitorDpiChanged method, so either property mush be set in base form class in which case it can be overriden by mistake in form designer, or WMDpiChanged must be used, but in that case it has to be copy pasted... and not only that method but some others because they are private... or some method hacking is in order...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Or we could read TLama's comment as being directed at the Embarcadero VCL maintainers!!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Time to file bug reports...

Comment: @Dalija, I haven't checked the source. What's worse, I misread the question (the OP already knows to make base form class). And for sure copy pasting implementation would be unstable evil. Shame on me anyway :)

Comment: Reported as https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27233